# Convergence of series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k}}{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to inspect the convergence of the following series
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k}}{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}}$$.

Because I am new to the whole series part it would be very nice if someone could explain to me how it goes. I have managed to show the convergence with ordinary series but with ceilings and floors it feels a bit more complicated.

Comment: Are you saying that without the floor, you can prove that this series converges? Or are you talking about other series? If so, which series are you talking about?

Comment: Other series… Like very simple series consisting of just k... 
So I was a bit shocked as well when this suddenly jumped up in the textbook without any explanation…

Comment: It diverges if $$ \frac{2^{k}}{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}} \to \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It diverges by a comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: You are right! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It diverges because it's a series of positive terms and the $k^{th}$ term does *not* tend to 0 as $k\rightarrow\infty$. This is a *necessary* condition for convergence, but it is *not sufficient*: the harmonic series provides a counterexample.

Comment: Okay, seems that I have just overstudied because even the simplest of things feel like mindblowers. Thanks for your contribution :)